# Just started ROR Lynda Tutorial, Error while trying to execute rails server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Just started ROR Lynda Tutorial, Error while trying to execute the rails server in terminal.

New to ROR. Followed tutorial closely and installed all necessary gems and files. Creating a simple CMS. However I'm stuck with the following error.

```
$ rails server
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.2.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I have installed MySQL server version 5.5.13. I have Rails version 3. I have the MySQL(0.3.2) gem file installed.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to fix this is to run

```
gem pristine --all
```

This rebuilds the Gems and should get rid of the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I see that most likely your setup is not right. You should do a 'bundle check' to see if all dependencies have been met, I am quite sure they haven't. If you haven't yet done a 'bundle install' you need to do so, if you've done that already, then the problem is that bundler wasn't able to install mysql2 gem version 0.2.6 (it must be mentioned somewhere either in you Gemfile or somehow in the Gemfile.lock in case you've got that from somewhere else). So you would then either bundle install will fix it, or if not, then you should probably do a 'bundle update mysql2'